# how to create loops in xml file in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-checkbox

I'm new to Android Programming.
I want to implement p: data table tag functionality as of prime faces in android.

I want a table layout in XML through which I can iterate over a list of values from bean along with a checkbox for each row.
Using checkbox listener I want that particular row to be editable and vice versa. and that row should contain text views which allow the user to edit the text and also add row functionality which add an empty row to table to allow a user to enter values and save it.

can anyone suggest how can I proceed?
Thank you.

Comment: You can edit and set styles programmatically in android, most of the cool features aren't necessarily done in purely XML.

Comment: Yes.I wrote custom style for a textview in styles.xml to become editable.Now how can i apply that custom style to textview whenever checkbox is clicked programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage all this in your Java class.
Here is a triggerless example for dynamically added checkboxes.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
    ll.addView(cb);
}
```

Here is a simple example. Simply put the event listener on the desired checkbox and do the processing according to what you want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private CheckBox checkBox1;
        private TextView tv1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
            tv1.setText("This is an example");

            checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
                        tv1.setText("Hi i am check");
                        tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }else {
                        tv1.setText("Hi i am not checked");
                        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

}

Comment: thank you.Then how can I implement checkbox listener so that when it is checked that particular should be editable so that user can modify the content of it.